# Navbar Class in HTML won't show some CSS attributes

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the only CSS attributes going through in the nText class are the inline display and font size.  The border attributes, padding, and text-decoration will not respond to being changed. 
The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ted's Lawn Care</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"> <img id="headText" src="headerLeftImage.jpg"/>
    <img id="headImage" src="headerImage.jpg"/></a>         
</div>
<div id="navbar">
    <img id="navImage" src="navBackground.jpg"/>
    <div id="navText">
        <p class="nText" id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="services"><a href="services.html">Services</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="rates"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
 *{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;

}
#header{
background-color: #BDB76B;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
border-bottom: 10px;
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
}
#headText{
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 15%
}
#headImage{
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 85%;
}
#navImage{
background-color: #66CD00;
width: 100%;
height: 8%;
position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 0; right: 0;
}
#navBar{
width: 100%;
height: 8%;
position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 0; right: 0;
}
#navText{
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 0; right: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.nText{
display: inline;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #9ACD32;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 80px;
font-size: 2em;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: none;`
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `nText` `inline-block;` `border-style:solid` and **your link text** `display:inline-block;` and `text-decoration none;`

As like this

```
    .nText{
    display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
border-style: solid;
    }
    .nText a{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

and **correct your** `id` in **css** change this `#navBar` into this `#navbar`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1a5bmxwe/2/)

```css
*{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;

}
#header{
background-color: #BDB76B;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
border-bottom: 10px;
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
}
#headText{
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 15%
}
#headImage{
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 85%;
}
#navImage{
background-color: #66CD00;
width: 100%;
height: 8%;
position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 0; right: 0;
}
#navbar{
width: 100%;
height: 8%;
position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 0; right: 0;
}
#navText{
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
top: 20%; left: 0; right: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.nText{
display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border-style:solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #9ACD32;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 80px;
font-size: 2em;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;`
    
}
.nText a{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"> <img id="headText" src="headerLeftImage.jpg"/>
    <img id="headImage" src="headerImage.jpg"/></a>         
</div>
<div id="navbar">
    <img id="navImage" src="navBackground.jpg"/>
    <div id="navText">
        <p class="nText" id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="services"><a href="services.html">Services</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="rates"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></p>
        <p class="nText" id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is border style wihout it border attributes dont work

```
.nText{
border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See here for corrections http://jsfiddle.net/16qx41k2/1/

There is a typo.

You wrote your id in camel case in the css. It is case sensitive.
change

```
#navBar {
...
}
```

to

```
#navbar {
...
}
```

Same rule applies to everywhere.

For the border, you have to add the `border-style: solid` if you wish to see the border.
You can of course have other styles such as `border-style:dashed`.